# How to install djangorestframework-gis-distance

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pip, gis

I am on Ubuntu and I tried to install djangorestframework-gis-distance

I followed the instructions and installed the dependencies which installed fine.
But when I install djangorestframework-gis-distance it gives an error of

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/aarush/git_fudo/food1_back/food1_back/env/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ntgn7sle/djangorestframework-gis-distance/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ntgn7sle/djangorestframework-gis-distance/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ntgn7sle/djangorestframework-gis-distance/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ntgn7sle/djangorestframework-gis-distance/setup.py", line 9, in <module>
        from pip.req import parse_requirements
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.req'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Which basically says I think that there is no file called pip.req.
Is there another way I can install djangorestframework-gis-distance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets see: https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-gis-distance/ . Latest version [1.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-gis-distance/1.0.0/) released Feb 7, 2016.

Requires Python 2.7 but not 3+. Django 1.7+ but most probably not Django 2+. The error message indicates `setup.py` uses forbidden API `pip.req` which was only available in `pip` < 19 (IIRC).

The bottom line: the package is abandoned and outdated. Forget about it.